# C# WinForms how to play 2 sounds in the same time

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using  the command: `SoundPlayer cave = new
     SoundPlayer(WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.Cave_Music;` to play a melody in the background, however if I want to add let's say a Beep in the same time with the melody, the melody stops. I couldn't find any answers on older questions of the same time, so how do I play 2 sounds in the same time? Prefferably booth of them from a Resorce.

Thanks alot !

Comment: I'm not even close to sure if this can help, but have you tried to make another instance of the SoundPlayer class and called the sound function from that instance...?

Comment: you should create another soundplayer name it `cave2` to play second sound.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It doesn't make any difference, when you play using second player, first playing sound will stop playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend to use DirectSound or similar API for such purposes.

Also, you can implement this using [System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx) class.

The multi-threaded example is [here](http://www.resolvinghere.com/sof/6240002.shtml).

Comment: Thanks alot, now it works. And thanks to the others for their answers too !

Comment: This is great research. Can you add some code from the example to your post? A great answer includes everything the viewer needs available without having to parse through the links.